# Chrome 81 -> 83 input[type="datetime-local"] enter key behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

The input[type="datetime-local"] behaviour have changed between chrome 81 and 83

on chrome <= 81, the datetime-local input calendar was enabled on click, and a keyup event was fired on enter key : [see behaviour on saucelabs - chrome 81](https://app.saucelabs.com/tests/f65e8ecbd83c477e87a5f7a6946d8741#2)

[image: on chrome 81]

on chrome 83, this behaviour have changed : the enter key triggers the opening of the calendar, and no keyup event is fired [see behaviour on saucelabs - chrome 83](https://app.saucelabs.com/tests/1026b783260844b0b8a50f5522f3cc24)

The following code (also on https://jsfiddle.net/os139hw6/)

```html
<input id="dt" type="datetime-local"/>
```

```js
document.querySelector("#dt").addEventListener("keyup", (ev) => {
    console.log(ev.keyCode);
});
```

shows keyup 13 events on < 81, nothing on >= 83

I use this keyup 13 event to validate/submit data, but it is no more possible; I have not found many changelog / details on this update / feature / bug but this [chromium change](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2015651) may be the one

moreover, even without any js, this disables the  to submit a form using enter within a datetime input : see https://jsfiddle.net/h0r4v516/

```html
<form id="frm">
<div>
  <label>This field cannot be used to submit the form using "enter" key</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="dt"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label>This field can be used to submit the form using "enter" key</label>
  <input type="text" id="txt"/>
</div>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

so is it possible to keep the old behaviour ? and if not, how can i now validate a datetime-local form input using keyboard...

Edit: created an issue on [chromium bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1086417)

Comment: Have you tried onchange?

Comment: onchange works but the enter key is a way for the user to indicate that the date is ok and ready for submission / save; the onchange does not provide this UX

Comment: Why would you want to only support keyboard-driven change?

Comment: tab / edit / enter to save field cycle on a form is fast

Comment: There's definitely work been done in this area recently where discussions were going on around specific behaviours such as this - see [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1001571) and [this follow up](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1041637).

Comment: [this is the one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1001571) nice catch @JamesThorpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this workaround to fix this behaivor:

First catch de event 'keydow' from the input date and prevent that the default action (open the popup)
At the same moment you can throw your own event to handle it as you like.

```
`
    $(document).on('keydown', "input[type='date']", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();        
            $(this).trigger('myOwnEvent');
        }
    });

`
```